# Jenkins - Can master node access source code held on slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cobertura, gcov

I have been conducted successful tests generating code coverage data on a c++ project using gcov, gcovr and Cobertura Jenkins plugin. In this simple project the build was done on the master node. In jenkins I could drill down into the coverage report to see the coverage at line level.

Now we are trying to expand the project into a real use case. In this distributed setup, we have a master node running jobs on a multitude of slaves. The coverage report works as before, except the source code display is not available.

Clearly this is because the report is shown by the master node, but the source is only checked out on the slave.

Is there a way to overcome this? Do I need to copy the source from the slave or can I get the master to do its own SVN checkout to have a parallel source tree?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've accomplished this in the past is to use the Copy to Slave plugin which can copy files from the slave back to the master.  However I've used it to copy unit test results back which are fairly small XML files.  If your source tree is really large, it might take a while.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin